# "StorePost"Request authorize() function works differently than expected

Tags: laravel

I want to validate the data sent with a POST request. For this I created my own request class with `php artisan make:request StorePostRequest`. By default this class is generated with two methods: public **authorize** and public **rules**. I have set the rules themselves and authorise is default false. Now when I send a POST request against the API with Insomnia or Postman I get a HTTP `403` response. If I set the return value authorise to true the data will be validated. What I do not understand. The I actually want everyone to be able to send data via POST request and not only authorised users. Is this a bug or do I have an understanding problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `authorize` method is to specify which kind of users with which authority can request the method. If you set it to true, it means that it doesn't have any limitations for the access (exactly what you need). But if you needed some validations for the user, you could put the `false` or `true` response in some condition block.